# There is no java resources folder in my eclipse maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, src, java-resources

In my eclipse maven project there is no java resources folder like this.

[image]

When I create my dynamic web application there is no java resources folder in it.  I tick the Generate web.xml deployment descriptor at the end also but there is no Java resources folder. Can you resolve my problem?

This is my project explorer. Can you see there is no java resources folder.

[image]

Comment: Please put more effort in your question.

Comment: @JFabianMeier sorry this is my first attempt. Is it correct now? Can you check this. Your contribution is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Which eclipse version are you using? I am using the newest stable version and the tree node "java resources" does not appear. It might have been called like that in older eclipse versions but I am not sure. The important thing is though, that you should have a tree node for "src/main/resources" or at least a hierarchical structure like

- src

  - main

    - resources

You can also compare your structure with a sample project which you can create from maven archetypes. Go to File > New > Project > Maven > Maven Project > Next > and select one of the sample archetypes like maven-archetype-webapp > enter an artifact name and finish. Now you can see how it should be displayed in eclipse correctly.